# Tags getting appended to dojo editor content

Tags: dojo, rich-text-editor

I have a dojo editor on a jsp page. The dojo editor is one of the required fields  and i have a validation in place for it. There is a scenario in which some tags are getting appended. I cannot find a particular pattern when it gets appended but most of the times it occurs after one selects and copies all the content and pastes on the editor. So the editor content in this case was

```
<div id="dijitEditorBody">content which user entered</div>
```

Issue: When the user deletes all content which was entered the tags are still there and get submitted. In this case atleast visually editor has no content but the field holds the following value:

```
    <div id="dijitEditorBody"></div>
```

or

```
   <div id="dijitEditorBody"><br /></div>
```

So it skips validation and displays an empty editor when data is retrieved from DB?

I am confused about why these tags are getting appended?
[image: Actual data entered]

[image: Editor Content]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Why are you pasting html code into the editor ?

Comment: @Phillipe I am sorry for the confusion.I am not pasting html code in the editor. In this instance "some editor content" is being copied and pasted on the editor. This content doesn't have this div tag.But somehow on submission I see that the editor contents have a div tag appended to it. I am not sure from where this div tag is coming in this instance.

Comment: What version of dojo are you using ?

Comment: version-1.6.1. I wanted to add that this issue is not happening all the time. It has happened only in this case. Most of the times its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In RichText.js, this snippet :

```
if(dojo.isIE || dojo.isWebKit || (!this.height && !dojo.isMoz)){
        // In auto-expand mode, need a wrapper div for AlwaysShowToolbar plugin to correctly
        // expand/contract the editor as the content changes.
        html = "<div id='dijitEditorBody'></div>";
        setBodyId = false;
    }else if(dojo.isMoz){
        // workaround bug where can't select then delete text (until user types something
        // into the editor)... and/or issue where typing doesn't erase selected text
        this._cursorToStart = true;
        html = "&nbsp;";
    }
```

Explains the reason why that tag is added...
Although you see it in your alertbox, I believe it's not present in the posted contents... right ?
The editor should take care of removing the extra-tags => not tested but pretty sure...

Comment: Most of the cases this tag is not present. But in this particular case the div tag did get displayed in the alertbox and was inserted into the database.

Comment: It's a bit hard to shoot in the dark like this... if you ever manage to reproduce the problem, please post more details. Maybie it will be of some help if you post your code.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your inputs and effort.